# MATLAB: imwrite with negative values and custom color map

Tags: image, matlab, color-mapping

I have a custom color map `cmap` that I use to display a matrix `X` that contains negative values. I display it using

```
image(X, 'CDataMapping', 'scaled');
colormap(cmap);
axis normal;
```

It works great, but now I would like to save the matrix as an image with that same color map.

When I try the following :

```
imwrite(X, cmap, 'test.tif');
```

I get an all-black image. I understand that tiff wants to map these into the 0 to 1 or 0 to 2^16 space, so I tried doing

```
X = X - min(X(:));
X = (X/max(X(:)))*(2^16);
X = uint16(X);
```

But then when I tried to save `X` with the `cmap`, the file was corrupted and wouldn't open. I tried regenerating the custom color map using the new scale of 0 to 2^16-1, but the image created from that also was unreadable.

Any ideas on how this might be accomplished?

Comment: Are you sure the image is all black, as in every pixel is a 0? Try displaying the image using `imagesc()`.

Comment: What do you mean by "I couldn't get what I wanted"? @jerad may be right – as you're output uint16 values you can't use `image` to display the data when you read the file back in.

Comment: The image is indeed all black - if I open it using `imread' and look at the pixel values, they are all zero.

Comment: horchler, I'll update the question and try to be more clear - thanks.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure how standard TIFF images with colormaps are (though it was added to the spec). Both OS X Preview and Photoshop CS6 refuse to open/display the images output by Matlab. Other programs show something but appear to not apply the colormap or apply it incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I finally resolved it:

In addition to modifying the matrix, I had to normalize the color map into the 0 to 1 space. I also had to multiple by the length of the color map instead of 2^16.

Here's what that ended up looking like:

```
cmap = cmap - min(cmap(:));
cmap = cmap/max(cmap(:));
N = size(cmap, 1);
X = X - min(X(:));
X = (X/max(X(:)))*N;
X = uint16(X);
imwrite(X, cmap, 'test.tif');
```

I hope this saves some of you the trouble it caused me!

Answer (score 0):

it seems like there's no image file format that supports 16 bit indexed color image saving:
TIFF does not support indexed colors, and PNG does not support 16 bit index.

Try converting to full RGB and save that as tiff:

```
rgb = ind2rgb( uint16(X), cmp ); % with X scaled as in your question
imwrite( rgb, 'myTiffImage.tif' ); % write the RGB image
```

Comment: TIFF does indeed support indexed images, but the baseline spec (6.0, 1992) only covers 4-bit and 8-bit.